# Comparing objects to see if they have equal values

Tags: java, android

```
public class LED {
    public boolean onState;
    public boolean updateRequired;
    public int Id;
    public String Key;
    public Drawable onStateDrawable;
    public Drawable offStateDrawable;
}

public class StateMachine{    
    private Map<Integer, LED> lamps = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I want to be able to detect that they have differences in state between two instances of StateMachine. I tried `instance1.equals(instance2)`but it says they're different even though they're the same.

Comment: Override `.equals (Object obj)` and `hashCode(0` in `class StateMachine`, and `class LED`. If equality of two `LED` objects is dependent on equality of `Drawable`, override both in that class, too.

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

`The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).`
If you want your comparison of StateMachines to be customized, you should override the equals method and implement the comparison.

In your case specifically, even though your 2 objects of StateMachine can store the exact same Map reference, as they are 2 different objects, by default they are not equal to each other

**UPDATE**: as noted in the comment, quote

```
it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method 
whenever equals method is overridden,
so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method,
which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.
```

Comment: Importantly *Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.*